# Read a row of a file starting at byte offset until new line

Tags: file, go, byte, reader

I am using os.ReadAt() to read certain rows in a csv/tsv file. However, I don't know how many bytes are in that row, I just need to read the line starting at the byte offset I specify until the newline.

```
buffer = make([]byte, 46)
os.ReadAt(buffer, 64) //Read at byte offset 64 and put contents in buffer
```

However, this only allows me to read 46 bytes of the line in.
Is there any way to read the entire line until the newline?

Thanks

Update:

I just create a struct that holds the offset and line length.. Should've done this in the beginning.. my bad

Answer (score 3):

One way is use the `bufio` pkg. An example of this is the following:

```
fd, err := os.Open("your_file.csv")
if err != nil { //error handler
    log.Println(err)
    return
}

reader := bufio.NewReader(fd) // creates a new reader

_, err = reader.Discard(64) // discard the following 64 bytes
if err != nil { // error handler
    log.Println(err)
    return
}

// use isPrefix if is needed, this example doesn't use it
// read line until a new line is found
line, _, err := reader.ReadLine() 
if err != nil { // error handler
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(line))
```

Another way to read the line, you can use `fd.Seek(64,0)` to jump to a specific byte like

```
_, err = fd.Seek(64, 0)  // Set the current position for the fd
if err != nil { // error handler
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

And afterward use the reader to read the line.

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(fd)

line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(line))
```

Comment: I have to step back in the file Im currently reading, so I can't just discard the next n bytes. I have to jump back to the top of the file sometimes. Can you put a negative number In discard?

Comment: No, but you can use `file.seek()` and create another `bufio.Reader` if you need it.

Comment: Yeah.. I was trying to avoid that.. but I guess thats the only option. Thanks!